# Magento 1.9: Check Cart contains only selected category of products

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

My observer condition based on Cart products, how to check Cart contains only selected category of products?

What event do I need to use?

Comment: which event you're using for the same?

Comment: @Sumit checkout_cart_save_after